# Microsoft SQL Server 2019 on linux always on pcs status error

Tags: linux, sql-server-2019, alwayson

This is a newly deployed environment and an error has been reported after executing the following command

```
pcs resource create sqlag ocf:mssql:ag ag_name=sqlag master notify=true
```

```
pcs resource create AVGListener ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=192.168.31.206 cidr_netmask=24
```

```
pcs constraint colocation add AVGListener sqlag-master INFINITY with-rsc-role=Master
```

```
pcs constraint order promote sqlag-master then start AVGListener
```

---

```
[root@sqlag01 ~]# pcs status
Cluster name: sqlcluster
Stack: corosync
Current DC: sqlag01 (version 1.1.21-4.el7-f14e36fd43) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Thu Oct 22 17:57:50 2020
Last change: Thu Oct 22 17:14:32 2020 by root via crm_resource on sqlag01

3 nodes configured
4 resources configured

Online: [ sqlag01 sqlag02 ]
OFFLINE: [ sqlag03 ]

Full list of resources:

 Master/Slave Set: sqlag-master [sqlag]
     sqlag      (ocf::mssql:ag):        FAILED sqlag01
     sqlag      (ocf::mssql:ag):        FAILED sqlag02
     Stopped: [ sqlag03 ]
 AVGListener    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Stopped

Failed Resource Actions:
* sqlag_start_0 on sqlag01 'unknown error' (1): call=1487, status=complete, exitreason='2020/10/22 17:57:50 Did not find AG row in sys.availability_groups',
    last-rc-change='Thu Oct 22 17:57:45 2020', queued=1ms, exec=5157ms
* sqlag_start_0 on sqlag02 'unknown error' (1): call=1487, status=complete, exitreason='2020/10/22 17:57:49 Did not find AG row in sys.availability_groups',
    last-rc-change='Thu Oct 22 17:57:44 2020', queued=0ms, exec=5145ms

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/disabled
  pacemaker: active/disabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

I suspect the mistake is caused by VIP, but I don't know how to eliminate it.Windows DNS Server used by DNS Server

Answer (score 0):

please try to do this.

```
pcs resource create AVGListener ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=192.168.31.206 nic="lo" cidr_netmask=32 iflabel="pgrepvip" op monitor interval=90s
```

please check your network name nic= "lo" or something else